# No composer options when right click

Tags: composer-php

I want to try to install laravel framework using composer. But i can't see any options 'Use composer here' when right click. But i successfully install composer when I check command line 'composer'. Is there any problem? I'm using WAMP and Windows 10 OS. Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"No, the feature was completely removed in the new installer."
https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5169

Answer (score 3):

If the context option doesn't appear you'll have to uninstall composer and install it again (maybe you didn't check the option to enable composer in contextual menu for windows).

Anyway the context menu is not necessary if you have composer installed. (or just download composer.phar [here](http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar))

Then open the cmd windows console (cmd.exe) and execute

```
cd "c:/the-path-to-the-folder-where-you-want-your-project"
```

then execute composer with php using (located in the folder where the project meants to be created):

```
c:/path-to-php/php.exe c:/path-to-composer-phar/composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

Answer (score 1):

While installing , select  "Install shell menu" option for getting composer option on mouse right click.

Answer (score 1):

In latest version composer "install menu" feature has been completely removed so you can just install the "composer.exe" by downloading from https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows . after installing composer you can open command prompt and go to the directory C://xampp/htdocs and run the installer commands to download.